# How to increment value until property value is same and id different javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an arry of objects called `arrList` and a parameter called `checkId`.

If the array of object has a duplicated `value` and `id !== checkId` it needs to increment the `value`. Do that until no duplicates are found. It needs to happen recursively

I have tried the following:

```js
const arrList = [
  { id: 11, value: null },
  { id: 14, value: 4 },
  { id: 28, value: 1 }, // need to be changed to '2'
  { id: 26, value: 3 },
  { id: 78, value: 1 }, 
  { id: 21, value: 6 },
  { id: 24, value: 8 }
];
const checkId = 78;

for (const res of arrList) {
  const duplicates = hasDuplicates(res, arrList);
  res.value = (res.id !== checkId && res.value >= duplicates.value)
    ? (res.value || 0) + 1
    : res.value;
}

console.log(arrList);

function hasDuplicates(item, list) {
  return list.find(e => e.value === item.value);
}
```

The expected result is:

```js
[
  { id: 11, value: null },
  { id: 14, value: 4 },
  { id: 28, value: 2 },
  { id: 26, value: 3 },
  { id: 78, value: 1 },
  { id: 21, value: 6 },
  { id: 24, value: 8 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way of doing that:

```js
const arrList = [
  { id: 11, value: null },
  { id: 14, value: 4 },
  { id: 28, value: 1 },
  { id: 26, value: 3 },
  { id: 78, value: 1 }, 
  { id: 21, value: 6 },
  { id: 24, value: 8 }
];
const checkId = 78;

const removeArrayDuplicates = array =>
  array.filter((item,
    index) => array.indexOf(item) === index);

while (arrList.map(e => e.value).length !== removeArrayDuplicates(arrList.map(e => e.value)).length) {
  for (let index = 0; index < arrList.length; index++) {
    if (arrList[index].id === checkId) continue;

    const duplicates = hasDuplicates(arrList[index], arrList);
    arrList[index].value = duplicates ? (arrList[index].value || 0) + 1 : arrList[index].value
  };
}

console.log(arrList);

function hasDuplicates(item, list) {
  return !!list.find(e => e.value === item.value);
}
```

You didn't specify what the action should be when `value = null` and in your code it overrides that with `1`. So in that case you got your expected outcome wrong. If you run my code snippet you will see that the outcome is slightly different as after the first iteration, the `null` element has a `value = 1` so now there is again a duplicat and this is why the code is going to loop for a second time, thus making the values increment twice.